# Setting repmgr witness node on Debian

Tags: repmgr

I am trying to set up repmgr version 5 on Debian with PostgtrSql 11.
Seems like the documentation is more oriented towards centos/RHEL.

When I am trying to setup the witnes node to start the repmgr daemon, I get an error without any idea where to look for for seeing what is the cause of the error.

This is my repmgr.conf file:

```
node_id=3
node_name='PG-Node-Witness'
conninfo='host=10.97.7.140 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2'
data_directory='/var/lib/postgresql/11/main'
failover='automatic'
promote_command='/usr/bin/repmgr standby promote -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
follow_command='/usr/bin/repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file --upstream-node-id=%n'
priority=60
monitor_interval_secs=2
connection_check_type='ping'
reconnect_attempts=6
reconnect_interval=8
primary_visibility_consensus=true
standby_disconnect_on_failover=true
repmgrd_service_start_command='sudo /etc/init.d/repmgrd start'  #??????
repmgrd_service_stop_command='sudo //etc/init.d/repmgrd stop'#??????
service_start_command='sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start postgresql@11-main.service'
service_stop_command='sudo /usr/bin/systemctl stop postgresql@11-main.service'
service_restart_command='sudo /usr/bin/systemctl restart postgresql@11-main.service'
service_reload_command='sudo /usr/bin/systemctl relaod postgresql@11-main.service'
monitoring_history=yes
log_status_interval=60
```

register is OK:

```
repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf witness register -h 10.97.7.97

INFO: connecting to witness node "PG-Node-Witness" (ID: 3)
INFO: connecting to primary node
NOTICE: attempting to install extension "repmgr"
NOTICE: "repmgr" extension successfully installed
INFO: witness registration complete
NOTICE: witness node "PG-Node-Witness" (ID: 3) successfully registered
```

repmgr daemon dry-run OK too:

```
$repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf daemon start --dry-run
INFO: prerequisites for starting repmgrd met
DETAIL: following command would be executed:
 sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start postg...@11-main.service
```

I setup /etc/default/repmgrd with:

```
REPMGRD_ENABLED=yes
```

and

```
REPMGRD_CONF="/etc/repmgr.conf"
```

But still get error when trying to run the daemon start:

```
$ repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf daemon start
```

I get:

```
NOTICE: executing: "sudo  /etc/init.d/repmgrd start"
ERROR: repmgrd does not appear to have started after 15 seconds
HINT: use "repmgr service status" to confirm that repmgrd was successfully started
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to run `repmgrd` as a systemd service,
According to the [docs](https://repmgr.org/docs/4.0/repmgrd-daemon.html) (for debian) you may first need to configure `/etc/default/repmgrd`,
My configuration looks like this:

```
# default settings for repmgrd. This file is source by /bin/sh from
# /etc/init.d/repmgrd

# disable repmgrd by default so it won't get started upon installation
# valid values: yes/no
REPMGRD_ENABLED=yes

# configuration file (required)
REPMGRD_CONF="/etc/repmgr/12/repmgr.conf"

# additional options
REPMGRD_OPTS="--daemonize=false"

# user to run repmgrd as
REPMGRD_USER=postgres

# repmgrd binary
REPMGRD_BIN=/bin/repmgrd

# pid file
REPMGRD_PIDFILE=/var/run/repmgrd.pid
```

Secondly, I would revisit `sudoers` (visudo) in order to check whether the `non-root` user can execute `sudo /etc/init.d/repmgrd start`.

Further, the user who runs repmgr commands should be able to write logs depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the correct command to start the repmgr daemon is:
repmgrd -f /etc/prepmgr.conf